# Session management location in oauth enable web application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, session, oauth

What is the location of session management, if we are developing oauth service(Facebook/ gmail) enabled web application (angular/react)? Where should I maintain the user seesions in hosted server or oauth service?

because timeout period is already defined in the oauth initial response.(after passing login credentials)

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is using local storage to store data what you need to save.It is useless for looking attribute in your server side.

Answer (score 0):

Session management is not correct here , 
javascript (react , angular and ... )  uses localStorage or IndexedDB to store variable in theme  , 
if you need to handle this data as a state , so you have to use Redux in your project  . 
redux is state management that can handle your state in hole of your project